# can i move Windows XP Pro from dead laptop to another PC?

Tags: licensing, windows-xp

my question is quite legal not technical.

My old Samsung Laptop is dead. It comes with Windows XP Pro.
I want to know that, can i install that Windows XP to another PC.

Is it allowed?
Will there be any licensing issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, but as I understand it -

You'll have to check the EULA to be certain, but typically no.  Typically OEM software is licensed to the specific hardware that it was originally installed on, and can't be moved to new hardware.

Comment: Legally -- correct.
http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/licensing_faq.aspx#fbid=VoEAzMVllzr

Comment: What makes you think a software license can be tied to hardware?

Comment: @Amicable Because you're not buying the software, you're getting a license to use it within the constraints specified by the license.  One of the reasons OEM installed copies of Windows are so much cheaper than retail copies are because they add additional constraints, like that you can move the software to other machines.  There's nothing physically stopping you from doing it, of course, but the licenses generally prohibit it.